# Salesforce connector Excel Add in - auto refresh doesn't trigger a data connection download

Tags: reporting, excel, salesforceexcelconnector, macros

I have an excel file which uses Salesforce connections (Salesforce Connector) to download the report file in csv format and updates the excel sheet with new data.

When i use the option Refresh All from Data, it automatically initiates the Salesforce.com connector to connect, download and update the new data.

I would like to refresh it every 5 minutes. (Initiate Salesforce Connector to connect, download and update the worksheet with latest data).

I have tried the following and unfortunately it did not work:

> Refresh All --> Connection Properties --> Usage --> Refresh Every 5 minutes.

[image]

It refreshes but it does not initiate the salesforce connector to download and reflect the new data in worksheet.

I have tried creating the following macro to check if it initiates the Refresh All to connect, download and update:

```
Sub Macro1()

    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub
```

How can I automatically initiate it every 5 minutes to reflect the latest data?